# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 4

Tags: android, encryption, camera, logcat

I try to run camera cipher of the guardian project, but when I push a button it got force close.
Here is my **logcat file:**

> 07-26 06:49:02.639 27157-27157/info.guardianproject.iocipher.camera
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                         Process: info.guardianproject.iocipher.camera, PID: 27157
>                                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {info.guardianproject.iocipher.camera/info.guardianproject.iocipher.camera.StillCameraActivity}:
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 4
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2774)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2238)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size
>   is 4
>                                                                                             at
>   java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>                                                                                             at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
>                                                                                             at
>   info.guardianproject.iocipher.camera.CameraBaseActivity.tryCreateCamera(CameraBaseActivity.java:222)
>                                                                                             at
>   info.guardianproject.iocipher.camera.CameraBaseActivity.initCamera(CameraBaseActivity.java:180)
>                                                                                             at
>   info.guardianproject.iocipher.camera.CameraBaseActivity.onResume(CameraBaseActivity.java:174)
>                                                                                             at
>   info.guardianproject.iocipher.camera.StillCameraActivity.onResume(StillCameraActivity.java:107)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
>                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5310)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2764)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2238) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>                                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

and this is my stillcamera.java file:

```
public class StillCameraActivity extends CameraBaseActivity {

    private String mFileBasePath = null;

    private boolean isRequest = false;
    private ArrayList<String> mResultList = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mFileBasePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("basepath");

        isRequest = getIntent().getAction() != null && getIntent().getAction().equals(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        mResultList = new ArrayList<String>();

        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_camera);
        buttonSelfie.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_switch_camera);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {      
        File fileSecurePicture;
        try {

            if (overlayView != null)
                overlayView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.flash);

            long mTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            fileSecurePicture = new File(mFileBasePath,"secure_image_" + mTime + ".jpg");

            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileSecurePicture));
            out.write(data);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            mResultList.add(fileSecurePicture.getAbsolutePath());

            Intent intent = new Intent("new-media");
              // You can also include some extra data.
              intent.putExtra("media", fileSecurePicture.getAbsolutePath());
              LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

            Intent intentResult = new Intent().putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mResultList.toArray(new String[mResultList.size()]));          
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intentResult);

            view.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    overlayView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                    resumePreview();
                }
            },100);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw that, but it didn't help me! :(

Comment: open `CameraBaseActivity.java`, find method `tryCreateCamera` (line 222). You may open it by clicking in correct place of your log in IDE

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
Intent intentResult = new Intent().putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mResultList.toArray(new String[mResultList.size()]));          
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intentResult);
```

to

```
Intent intentResult = new Intent().putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mResultList.toArray(new String[mResultList.size() - 1]));          
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intentResult);
```

Comment: the list size is 5 and its starting from zerp, so you have to set this in your code, new String[mResultList.size()-1]

Comment: I did that, but it didn't work!! :(